# Is there a way to use template literals for fetch request?

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I'd like to define a function that makes a fetch request based on its parameter so I can simplify the fetch calls inside componentDidMount(). I've tried the code below but it gives an Unexpected token error for the setState function. Is there a way to use the parameter of the function inside then()?

```
 constructor() {
    super();
    // cases in date order from 1 to 5. Cases5 is the latest.
    this.state = {
      cases1: [],
      cases2: [],
      cases3: [],
      cases4: [],
      cases5: [],
    };
  }

componentDidMount() {
    fetch("/cases/1")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((cases1) => this.setState({ cases1 }));

    fetch("/cases/2")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((cases2) => this.setState({ cases2 }));

    fetch("/cases/3")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((cases3) => this.setState({ cases3 }));

    fetch("/cases/4")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((cases4) => this.setState({ cases4 }));

    fetch("/cases/5")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((cases5) => this.setState({ cases5 }));
  }

  fetchCaseData = (index) => {
    fetch(`/cases${index}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((`cases${index}`) => this.setState({ `cases${index}` }));
  }
```

Comment: You are missing a slash in the .then((`cases${index}`) => this.setState({ `cases${index}` })); the line  when calling fetch.  Try,   'cases/${index}' as argument for fetch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't simply declare a dynamic name for a variable. You can however set dynamic keys for an object using brackets notation but not object shorthand syntax

Updated code will look like below

```
 .then((val) => this.setState({ [`cases${index}`]: val }));
```

Comment: But if you see his state you can see he is not setting an object, It is just a normal state variable

Comment: @ThanveerShah and how is `this.setState({ [`cases${index}`]: val }));` setting an object. Perhaps you are confusing it with how state is updated with react hooks

Comment: Thanks. It's what I was looking for.